# Find and replace character with control character

Tags: windows, windows-xp, visual-studio, find-and-replace, control-characters

Is it possible to find and replace a character with a control character?  Given the text

one,two,three

I want to Find `,` and replace with `\n` (new line).  So the result becomes

one
two
three

I am using Visual Studio, but I believe this applies to most any text editor in Windows.

Comment: Have you looked at UltraEdit?  It may have the ability to do this: http://www.ultraedit.com/

Comment: And to be clear this functionality would be dependent on the editor not the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010, use Quick Replace (control-H) and turn on "Use: Regular Expressions" under "Find options".  You can then specify \n to insert a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a method that works in a variety of different editors.

<strike>In Visual Studio  `\u000d\u000a` might work</strike>

In vim you would use `\r`

Other programs prabably have different methods

Comment: That placed literals in my string.  Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/) you can do a regexp search/replace using control characters. I did a quick search for a similar option on the VS2010 support boards; it looks like it wasn't implemented.